# populate a dataframe column based on a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
vehicle_make    vehicle_model   vehicle_year
Toyota  Corolla 2016
Hyundai Sonata  2016
Cadillac    DTS 2006
Toyota  Prius   2014
Kia Optima  2015
```

I want to add a new column 'vehicle_make_category' which populates based on a list i have

```
luxury=['Bentley',
'Maserati',
'Hummer',
'Porsche',
'Lexus']

non_luxury=['Saab',
'Mazda',
'Dodge',
'Volkswagen',
'Kia',
'Chevrolet',
'Hyundai',
'Ford',
'Nissan',
'Honda',
'Toyota'
]
```

How can accomplish this? I have tried using

```
df['vehicle_make_category']=np.where(df['vehicle_make']=i for i in luxury, 'luxury')
```

but it doesnt work...

Comment: create a new dataframe of brand-luxury/non.  then join the two

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
df["vehicle_make_category"] = None
df.loc[df["vehicle_make"].isin(luxury), "vehicle_make_category"] = "luxury"
df.loc[df["vehicle_make"].isin(non_luxury), "vehicle_make_category"] = "non_luxury"
```

Comment: Running this code returns NaN for all the values in the "vehicle_make_category" if this column hasn't been created already.

Answer (score 1):

Use `isin` and also add a condition to `np.where` that fills the gaps for a condition not evaluated as true

```
df['vehicle_make_category'] = np.where(df.vehicle_make.isin(luxury),'luxury','non-luxury')

  vehicle_make vehicle_model  vehicle_year vehicle_make_category
0       Toyota       Corolla          2016            non-luxury
1      Hyundai        Sonata          2016            non-luxury
2     Cadillac           DTS          2006            non-luxury
3       Toyota         Prius          2014            non-luxury
4          Kia        Optima          2015            non-luxury
```

---

Using [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) we can create a conditions list and assign values based on a condition being true

```
conditions = [df.vehicle_make.isin(luxury),df.vehicle_make.isin(non_luxury)]

df['vehicle_make_category'] = np.select(conditions,['luxury','non-luxury'],default='no-category')

  vehicle_make vehicle_model  vehicle_year vehicle_make_category
0       Toyota       Corolla          2016            non-luxury
1      Hyundai        Sonata          2016            non-luxury
2     Cadillac           DTS          2006           no-category
3       Toyota         Prius          2014            non-luxury
4          Kia        Optima          2015            non-luxury
```

Comment: This would assign `non-luxury` category to cars not in `nonluxury` list.

Comment: smart use of `np.select` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the column via list comprehension:

```
df['vehicle_make_category'] = [
    'luxury' if row.vehicle_make in luxury
    else 'non_luxury'
    for _, row in df.iterrows()
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can us df.join

You'll have to make a new dataframe identifying luxury/nonluxury.

```
veh = ['toyota','hyundai','cadillac']
yr = [2016,2016,2016]
lux = ['non','non','lux']

#recreating your lux/non layout
n_lux = [veh[0],veh[1]]
lux = [veh[2]]

#then making a new column
b = ['non' if v in n_lux else 'lux' for v in veh]


A = pd.DataFrame(np.array([veh,yr]).T)
B =pd.DataFrame(np.array([veh,b]).T)
pd.concat([A,B],axis = 1, keys = [0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `lookup_df` from the lists for `non_luxury` and `luxury`.

```
lookup_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'vehicle_make': luxury + non_luxury,
    'vehicl_make_category': (["luxury"] * len(luxury))+(["non_luxury"] * len(non_luxury))
})
```

Then `left join` on the original `df` that you have.

```
df.merge(lookup_df, how='left',left_on='vehicle_make', right_on='vehicle_make')
```

Output:

```
    vehicle_make    vehicle_model   vehicle_year    vehicle_make_category
0   Toyota               Corolla      2016             non_luxury
1   Hyundai               Sonata      2016             non_luxury
2   Cadillac               DTS        2006               NaN
3   Toyota                Prius       2014             non_luxury
4   Kia                   Optima      2015             non_luxury
```